# Hibernate transitive collection mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working with Hibernate 3.6 version, with xml mapping files. In my case I have three mapped entities, which are **Detector**, **Antenna** and **Location**. Basically, having `Detector`->`Set<Antenna>` and `Location`->`Set<Antenna>` relations, I would like to have also `Detector`->`Set<Location>` available.

Each **Detector** has a Set of Antenna entities, mapped like that:

```xml
<set name="_Antennas" table="tantenna" inverse="true" cascade="all">
    <key>
        <column name="id_detector" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="Antenna" />
</set>
```

Also each **Antenna** belongs to a specific Location and to a specific Detector. That's the **many-to-one** mapping to refer that:

```xml
<many-to-one name="_Detector" class="com.tadic.model.detector.Detector"
            column="id_detector" />

<many-to-one name="_Location" class="com.tadic.model.location.Location"
            column="id_location" />
```

In the same way, **Location** has a Set of its Antennas:

```xml
<set name="_Antennas" table="tantenna">
    <key>
        <column name="id_location" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.tadic.model.detector.Antenna" />
</set>
```

So Detector knows about its Antennas, Antennas know about their Detector and Location. Location entity has a set of its Antennas, but *tlocation* table has no foreign-keys.

However, I'm interested in knowing all the Locations of a Detector in a specific point. I know I can do it writing an HQL, but I would like to know if this is possible when Detector loads, just mapping it as a Set of Location entities.

Remember *tlocation* table has no *iddetector* column to link it with, also I think there's no need for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right from a database point

tdetector [1]--[id_detector]-->[n] tantenna

tlocation [1]--[id_location]-->[m] tantenna

Meaning tantenna has a column tuple of  (id_detector, id_location) and is essentially a link table between tdetector and tlocation. This could be used to facilitate a many-to-many mapping between Detectors and Locations.

And here is the mapping fragment for the Detector hibernate mapping.

```
<set name="locations" table="tantenna">
    <key column="id_detector" />
    <many-to-many class="com.tadic.model.location.Location" column="id_location" />
</set>
```

One more thing. In my experience, having such a complex relations scheme mapped on the ORM does not come without cost. Even if hibernate finds your mapping files to be fine during the session factory initialization, I urge you to test thoroughly and, if necessary, specify some relations to be read-only (i.e. only useful when reading data) with insert="false" update="false".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks well. Of course, I was thinking about define it as a read-only collection, also lazy-loaded, but to avoid executing an HQL for each detector I want to load locations for. That way it's possible to load the collection directly from the Entity.

Comment: It definitelly works! I don't know why I didn't think about stablishing the antenna table as a pivot table. Well done ;-)